# Changes to VSTOAddin.dll.config not recognized at runtime

Tags: c#, vsto

I'd like to better understand how VSTOAddin.dll.config files work in VSTO.

I don't understand why I can't edit the config file using Notepad and have those changes reflected the next time my add-in runs (similar to the following article).

I've successfully located and manually edited my User Settings config file. But can't do the same for the Application Settings config file. Why?

I understand that changes should be made through code or at design time in VS.

Help?!?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8104247-3609-42f7-8e06-71860f3f81e2/changes-to-outlookaddindllconfig-not-recognized-at-runtime-how-to-make-responsive-like?forum=vsto

--EDIT--

Thanks PetLahev, I'm actually doing doing things a little differently. I have three VSTO addins that all reference a common assembly. The settings are associated with the common assembly.

Is that allowed? I notice that the assembly is actually running from %appdata%\local\assembly..

But even if i move my ClassLibrary1.dll.config file to %appdata%\local\assembly.. I can't change it via Notepad and see the modification reflected in my app.

Comment: Using reflection, I can see that each Application Setting has a 'Default Value' set in the class file.

Is it using these values every time? If so, why bother having the .config file stored outside of the Assembly?

I tried stepping through my code and calling Settings.Default.Reload(), Settings.Default.Reset(), Settings.Default.Upgrade() etc and nothing made any difference.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom section as described in the third part of this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which application you use, I tried Excel and it's pretty straightforward

My app.config looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MyUserSettings" serializeAs="String">
                <value>My user settings</value>
            </setting>
        </ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MyAppSettings" serializeAs="String">
                <value>My Application settings</value>
            </setting>
        </ConfigSettingTest.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

and code that reads the userSettings and applicationSettings is simple like that

```
 public static void test()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.MyUserSettings);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.MyAppSettings);
        }
```

if I go to the bin folder and change the value via Notepad, and then run Excel, I'll get my changed values

Comment: Thanks PetLahev. That works for me as well. I actually have 3 Office Add-ins all referencing a common dll. And the common dll has the settings. I'll do some testing to see whether that's the problem.

Comment: PetLahev, any idea why it doesn't work when the app.config is for a referenced assembly?